# python function skipping around

Tags: python, function

My intent is to read a list from a file, pick a random number from that list and remove it, then resave the list. Sometimes the function works fine, sometimes not.

```
choices=[]

with open("C:\\choices.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f: 
        choices.append(int(line.strip()))
        
if len(choices)==0:
        choices=[0,1,2,3,4,5]

num=rdm.randint(0,5)

def chooseline(myList, myNum):
    print("before if num= "+str(myNum))
    
    if not myNum in myList:
        myNum=rdm.randint(0,5)
        chooseline(myList,myNum)
        print("In NOT-IF num= "+str(myNum))#<-- Need to move before chooseline to print. ok
    else:
        myNum=myList.pop(myList.index(myNum))      
        print("in Else num= "+str(myNum))
    
    print("end num= "+str(myNum))
    return myNum


newnum= chooseline(choices,num)

with open("C:\\choices.txt", "w") as f:
    for e in choices:
        f.write(str(e) +"\n")
```

As long as the random number is in the list the function returns as expected, but if the first number is not on the list, it seems to loop back.

```
runfile('...')
before if num= 0
in Else num= 0
end num= 0

runfile('...')
before if num= 2
in Else num= 2
end num= 2

runfile('...')
before if num= 2 #ok not in list 
before if num= 0 #ok chooses new number, but not in list
before if num= 4 # chose 4, in list
in Else num= 4 # as expected
end num= 4 #<----- expect to stop here and return 4
In NOT-IF num= 4
end num= 4 #
In NOT-IF num= 0
end num= 0
```

Comment: You're calling `chooseline()` recursively, and when the "inner" call is finished, the "outer" call keeps running where it left off.

Comment: It would be simpler to use a loop instead of recursion.

Comment: Also, the NOT-IF print statement is showing the newly chosen value of myNum, which is probably not the same value that triggered the if.

Comment: @John Gordon obvious now that you said it. Doh!

Comment: @John Gordon obvious now that you said it. Doh! I knew the Not-if was showing the newly chosen number before printing it's statement now I know why. -Bamar yes simpler, especially for only 6 elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example without the recursion as mentioned in the comments:

```
import random

choices = []

with open("choices.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        choices.append(int(line.strip()))

if len(choices) == 0:
    choices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

num = random.randint(0, 5)


def choose_num_in_list(max_attempts=100):
    chosen_number = -1
    attempts = 0
    while chosen_number == -1 and attempts < max_attempts:
        candiate_number = random.randint(0, 5)
        attempts = attempts + 1
        if candiate_number in choices:
            chosen_number = candiate_number
    return chosen_number


newnum = choose_num_in_list()
if(newnum != -1):
      choices.pop(choices.index(newnum))
      print(f"Removed {str(newnum)} from the list")
else:
    print("Failed to remove a number from the list")

with open("choices.txt", "w") as f:
    for e in choices:
        f.write(str(e) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier and more efficient approach ...

```
import random

lines = []
with open('choices.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        lines.append(int(line.rstrip()))
    file.close()

with open('choices.txt', 'w') as file:
    if len(lines) > 1:
        number = lines[random.randint(0, len(lines) - 1)]
        for line in lines:
            if line != number:
                file.write(f'{line}\n')
    file.close()
```